# Laravel и <code> tag

Tags: php, laravel

Как реализовывают вывод html тэгов в laravel? Пишут свой парсер строки?

Например сохранил такой комментарий в базу:

```
блабла <script>alert(1);</script> блабла...
<code><script>alert(1);</script></code>
блабла... блабла...
```

Нужно что-бы

```
<code><script>alert(1);</script></code>
```

Отобразилось как html

А остальное как как комментарий!?

Comment: это вам нужно регэксп писать,а выводить как реьд,это надо выводить с восклицательными знаками
$html = str_replace('/pateern/')
{!! $html !!}

Comment: может тэг <pre>  поможет?